# Django OneToOneField with multiple of the same -- related_name

Tags: django

Sorry for the none-descriptive title, but I didn't really have a clue as to how to word this.

Say I have two models as such:

```
class Person(...):
  name = ... #have an attribute

class Family(...):
  mum = models.OneToOneField(Person)
  dad = models.OneToOneField(Person)
```

When I have a family containing `mum` and `dad`, I would think calling `dad.family` would yield me the family `dad` is in. However, I get an error message saying that this clashes with the `mum` attribute. The solution here is to use `relative_name`s. But calling the family from `mum`s side something else than from `dad`s feels weird for me. WHy can't I just call `dad.family`? Could someone explain to me what exactly is clashing here?

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose the above is just an example for OneToOneFields.

But if it's a snippet from from some real-world code, just be prepared that your software *will* most probably have to handle families with varying number of parents (usually 1-2), of any gender combination.

Also if "mum" and "dad" is defined as "being a parent of gender G", it could be more useful storing gender information in the Person object, so you don't have to manually move a Person from "mum" to "dad" if gender information is updated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that, given your model, a `Person` could be a `mum` to one Family, and a `dad` to a different family.

In that case, a query like this would be ambiguous:

```
pat = Person.objects.get(name='Pat')
family1.mum = pat
family1.save()

family2.dad = pat
family2.save()

pat.family # Which family do we want?
```

For that reason, you need to define a reverse relation name for each one (family_as_mum and family_as_dad, for instance)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But, does a OneToOneField not guarantee that this doesn't happen?

Comment: No, the OneToOneField only guarantees uniqueness within that field. So all of the `mum`s are distinct, and all of the `dad`s are distinct, but nothing stops a person from being both.

Comment: Guess I should read up more on the exact definition of a one to one relationship then. Thanks again.

Comment: If you're familiar with databases, think of it as a foreign key with a 'UNIQUE NOT NULL' constraint -- In your case, you have two columns, each `UNIQUE`, but they're independent of each other.

Comment: I like the way Django treats LGBT

Answer (score 2):

I know the answer above does answer the question of "why is it clashing", and I know it is an old question. However, I came across it trying to come up with a way to have the code restrict the entries in one column based on the entries in the other. I did not find a sufficient answer, but managed to puzzle it out myself. Below is an answer to a question that isn't directly asked, but may be helpful to others.

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Family(models.Model):
  mum = models.OneToOneField(Person, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='family_as_mum', null=True)
  dad = models.OneToOneField(Person, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='family_as_dad', null=True)

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if Family.objects.filter(mum=self.dad).exists() or Family.objects.filter(dad=self.mum).exists() or self.mum == self.dad:
      return #any person can only be a mum or a dad, not both
    else:
      super(Family, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

  def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if Family.objects.filter(mum=self.dad).exists() or Family.objects.filter(dad=self.mum).exists() or self.mum == self.dad:
      return #same as save, don't want them to update a family member in an invalid way
    else:
      super(Family, self).update(*args, **kwargs)

  @staticmethod
  def get_family(person):
    if Family.objects.get(mum=person).exists():
      return Family.objects.get(mum=person)
    elif Family.objects.get(dad=person).exists():
      return Family.objects.get(dad=person)
    else:
      return None
```

*note, found the @staticmethod [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317197/django-model-method-with-self-instance), thought it might be useful to have a function to find the family associated with a parent, since we may not know up front if a person is a mum or a dad