# Django model method with self instance

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to move some functional logic into a model's method (instead of in the views), where I think it belongs:

```
class Spans(models.Model):
    snow = models.IntegerField()
    wind = models.IntegerField()
    exposure = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    module_length = models.IntegerField()
    max_roof_angle = models.IntegerField()
    building_height = models.IntegerField()
    importance_factor = models.IntegerField()
    seismic = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    zone = models.IntegerField()
    profile = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    tilt_angle = models.IntegerField()
    span = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=15)

    def get_spans(self, snow_load, wind_speed, module_length):
        """
        Function to get spans.
        """
        spans = self.objects.filter(
            snow=snow_load,
            wind=wind_speed,
            exposure='B',
            module_length__gte=module_length,
            max_roof_angle=45,
            building_height=30,
            importance_factor=1,
            seismic=1.2,
            zone=1,
            profile='worst'
        ).order_by('snow', 'module_length', 'span')
        return spans
```

However, I am a little unsure how to call it. In the shell I have tried:

```
>>> possible_spans = Spans.get_spans(0, 85, 54)
```

or

```
>>> possible_spans = Spans.get_spans(Spans, 0, 85, 54)
```

but I get an error:

```
TypeError: unbound method get_spans() must be called with Spans instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
```

or

```
TypeError: unbound method get_spans() must be called with Spans instance as first argument (got ModelBase instance instead)
```

I know I am missing something fundamental in python logic here, but I'm not sure what it is.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method needs to be called either with the instance, as the method call makes it as the default self arg. For example,

```
instance = Spans.objects.get(id=1)
instance.get_spans(0, 85, 54)
```

Or if you can want to call using class itself. You would have to pass the instance manually

```
instance = Spans.objects.get(id=1)
Spans.get_spans(instance, 0, 85, 54)
```

Update:
What you are looking for could be achieved using a static method

```
@staticmethod
def get_spans(snow_load, wind_speed, module_length):
        """
        Function to get spans.
        """
        spans = Spans.objects.filter(
            snow=snow_load,
            wind=wind_speed,
            exposure='B',
            module_length__gte=module_length,
            max_roof_angle=45,
            building_height=30,
            importance_factor=1,
            seismic=1.2,
            zone=1,
            profile='worst'
        ).order_by('snow', 'module_length', 'span')
        return spans
```

Now you could directly do,

```
Spans.get_spans(0, 85, 54)
```

Comment: Ok - then this function should probably not be a model method after all. I am actually intending to query the whole Spans table to get a query_set of `Spans` objects.

Comment: Intresting. I haven't come across static methods before.

Comment: Yeah its actually an interesting concept which could help to deal with situations similar to yours.

Comment: Except really this should be a job for a custom model manager.

Answer (score 0):

I arrived here with the same problem (I know it's an old question).

After some research this is how I proceeded:

- I consider `get_spans` a [class method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) (because it needs to access a class attribute of the same class: `Spans.objects`)
- Implementation:

  1. Apply `@classmethod` decorator
  2. Use `cls` as first method parameter
  3. Call the other method as `cls.objects.filter`.

Would look like this:

```
@classmethod # Steps 1 & 2
def get_spans(cls,snow_load, wind_speed, module_length):
        """
        Function to get spans.
        """
        # Step 3
        spans = cls.objects.filter( 
            snow=snow_load,
            wind=wind_speed,
            exposure='B',
            module_length__gte=module_length,
            max_roof_angle=45,
            building_height=30,
            importance_factor=1,
            seismic=1.2,
            zone=1,
            profile='worst'
        ).order_by('snow', 'module_length', 'span')
        return spans
```